# AWS CLI Get private subnets for VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-vpc

I have a script that starts some ECS tasks. To run the tasks I have to provide the private subnets in which the tasks can run. However, at the moment I'm copying and pasting the private subnet Ids from the AWS console into my script, which is a bit clunky, so I'm try to use the AWS CLI to obtain the private subnets in a scripted way.

I already figured out how to get the VPC Id but I seem to be having issues filtering the subnet results in such a way that:

a) I only get the private subnets
b) I only get the Ids of those subnets

What I have right now is:

```
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-0123456789
```

How can I add 'a' and 'b' to this command (pref. without any external or 3rd party tooling)?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/868038/aws-cli-list-private-subnets

Comment: Easiest would be to tag subnets as private and public. Its not easy to differentiate private and public subnets otherwise.

Comment: It looks to me like that the `MapPublicIpOnLaunch` indicates if the subnet is public or private, I mean, AWS must be able to distinguish between public and private. It's more about, how do I query for attributes with a specific value in the result set.

Comment: Technically private instances can also  have `MapPublicIpOnLaunch` set to `true`. But if you are consistent in creating subnets  with different values of `MapPublicIpOnLaunch`, then it will also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using a JMESPath expression in the `--query` parameter I was able to get only the private subnets:

```
 aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-0123456789 --query 'Subnets[?MapPublicIpOnLaunch==`false`].SubnetId'
```

Result:

```
[
    "subnet-0123456789",
    "subnet-9876543210"
]
```

Comment: I think a note should be given, that this is not a generic solution, and its only applicable to your use case. Otherwise, others may think its always the case that `MapPublicIpOnLaunch` is `false` for private subnets.

Comment: Modify  
aws ec2 describe-subnets --filter Name=vpc-id,Values=vpc-0123456789 --query 'Subnets[?State==`available`].SubnetId'